# How to communicate with a webpage via browser plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk, message-passing

How can I communicate from a JavaScript code of a webpage to the main code of the add-on?

For example, something like this: If some element is clicked, in the corresponding event handler of the page script, which is the syntax that can be used to send some message to the main code?

Specifically, [something like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_frame/#Communicating_with_feames), where the *frame* now must be replaced by a generic webpage. Is it possible?

Edit: I have tried the suggested code, but how I had said, the application returns this error:

> *console.error: sherlock: 
>       Message: ReferenceError: document is not defined
>         Stack:
>       A coding exception was thrown in a Promise resolution callback.
>       See https://developer.mozilla.org/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise
>
>           Full message: ReferenceError: document is not defined*

Previously my question, I had infact tried something similar without any effect.

Comment: No real question here.. What have you tried ? What have you researched ? Anything at all?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

"Developers trust Stack Overflow to help solve coding problems" - I don't see a coding problem here to be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is not as trivial as it may seem at first sight. I had also thought of a logic of the type described in the Pogrindis' response.

But here, in the case of interaction between the main script (i.e. that of the add-on) and generic script of arbitrary documents, the pattern is different.

In summary, the interaction takes place in this way:

- It is required the API *page-mod*.
- Through the property *includes* of the object *PageMod* you create a reference to the document, specifying the URI (wildcards are allowed).
- Via the *contentScriptFile* property it is set the URL of the *.js* file that will act as a vehicle between the main code and that of the document.

Here's an example that refers to the specific needs of the context in which I am. We have:

- an add-on code (the main code);
- a [Sidebar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar) type html document (gui1.html) loaded in the file that I
  use as a simple UI (I advise against the use of [Frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_frame), since it does
  not support many typical HTML features - eg the click on a link,
  etc.) containing a link to a second document (gui2.html) which will then
  be loaded into the browser tab (I needed this trick because the
  Sidebar does not support *localStorage*, while it is necessary for me);
- a script in the document.

We must create an exchange of information between the two elements. In my case the exchange is unidirectional, from the page script to the main one.

Here's the code (main.js):

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "resource://path/to/document/gui2.html",
    contentScriptFile: data.url("listen.js"),
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on("gotElement", function(elementContent) {
            console.log(elementContent);
        });
    }
});
```

and in the html page script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

[...]

SOWIN = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("win") > -1) ? "win" : "nix";
            if (SOWIN == "win") {
            window.postMessage("win","*");
            } else {
            window.postMessage("Linux","*");
            }
[...]

</script>
```

Finally in the JS file (listen.js) to be attached to the page script:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
   self.port.emit("gotElement", event.data);
}, false);
```

This is just a small example, but logic I would say that it is clear. The uploaded content scripts are not accessible directly from main.js (i.e. the add-on), but you can create a *bidirectional* communication through the exchange of messages. To achieve this we have to put ourselves in listening the event *Attach* of the page-mod. Then, it is passed a worker object to the listener; that worker may be used by the add-on for the exchange of messages.

Here are the references to have an exhaustive picture:

[Interacting with page scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts)

[Communicating with other scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Communicating_With_Other_Scripts)

[page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod)

[port](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/port)

[Communicating using "port"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port)

[postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

[Communicating using postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_postMessage)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

```
document.onload = function() {
  var elementYouWant = document.getElementById("someID");

  elementYouWant.onclick = console.log("Yup.. It was clicked..");
};
```

[Reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried the afdEventHandler in the main code, but it seemed it was needed some library (to define the window object). After having put the *require* syntax, the code did not work too.( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils)

Comment: @Bento please add your code to the question so we can see what's wrong./

Comment: I hope to solve. I will test your reference  later because now I am on phone and it is hard writing.